# Does this diet make any sense?

Tags: diet

This is my first question on Health, but I've used Stackoverflow for many years. Thanks for reading!

I am not a nutritionist, I don't study the field. I am just wondering about a diet I recently thought of.

Here's the rational behind, I'm just going with a common sense feeling, and what I state as the rationale behind might be wrong, but here it is. I believe lipids give 9 units of energy and are slow burning, and sugars give 4 units of energy and are fast burning. (I can't find the source of those units of 9 and 4 "energy units", but it sticked, if someone can let me know where it might be coming from)

- Breakfast: eat fatty cheese only, e.g. Brie for example, 30% fat, with coffee. That gives me a good slow burning energy base to start the day with, and with the coffee I can avoid feeling hungry until 12-13.
- Lunch time: eat a full meal from any restaurant, with enough calories to continue through the day. Can be anything.
- Dinner time: eat soup based food, vegetables, salad. carrots, celeries, lentils, water, tomatoes, olives, etc.

After doing this for 2 weeks, I actually had some positive results, been losing some weight.

Does that diet make any sense?

Comment: It may work for you w.r.t. losing weight, but you need to be careful with fats and restaurant food, [see here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGGQxJLuVjg).

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Since you've got enough rep on stackexchange to cast close votes, I'm sure you understand what I mean when I say the question is unclear, too broad, and primarily opinion based. That's the trifecta of close reasons.

Comment: There are really too many variables for us to say what might be helping you with this diet. Apart from that, the energy intake is not the only aspect of food you should consider; fiber and nutrients are important. So is your intake of water and exercise. But I can help with units of energy - it refers to kcal/g i.e. kilocalories (also known as food calories) per gram.

Comment: I've lost 8 kilos so far, and not losing more at the moment. But I'm still feeling my body is transforming. If this diet works for you, please upvote the question just to situate myself. I'm going to start combining some exercise to my diet now.